# How to get around logging in when sending HTTP Request

Tags: excel, vba, oauth-2.0, xmlhttprequest

I need to get an access token from the `api`, however when going to retrieve it using the `http` request, I continue getting an

> "error: bad client".

I have nailed this down to it being used to having a login window popping up and the user logging in to authenticate themselves. My filemma is that I am not exactly sure how to make that happen.

I have tried to send the username and password as  variables for the login page to read, but that has not worked. I have also tried to make vba open up internet explorer and login before sending the request. Neither of these has worked out very well.

```
Sub grabNewAccessToken()
Dim xmlhttp As Object
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")


Dim accessToken As String

URL1 = "https://api.channeladvisor.com/oauth2/token"

xmlhttp.Open "POST", URL1, False

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "access_type", "offline"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic [client secret]"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form- urlencoded"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Body", "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=xxxxxx"
xmlhttp.send

accessToken = xmlhttp.responseText
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Value = accessToken
End Sub
```

The best case scenario is that it returns an access token from my API to a cell in the worksheet. What is currently happening is me receiving

> "error: invalid client"

Comment: Can you add more details ? _I need to get an access token from the api_ Witch api ? Do you have the app registered ? I think you do not know the oAuth2 protocol. I suggest you to read [oAuth documentation](https://oauth.net/2/)

Comment: @Max I do know the oauth2.0 protocol. The API  is very clearly listed within the code as 'https://api.channeladvisor.com' My issue seems to be this. I am trying to run this code in excel VBA. Having done testing in Postman before, I can say that it normally pops up with a window that requires you to log in to channeladvisors website. This is not something that happens in VBA, and so instead my returned output is the _error: invalid client_